# Console.IsOutputRedirected not changing on SetOut

Tags: c#

As of my understanding this C# code:

```
var b1 = Console.IsOutputRedirected;
Console.SetOut(new StringWriter());
var b2 = Console.IsOutputRedirected;
Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()) { AutoFlush = true });
var b3 = Console.IsOutputRedirected;
Console.WriteLine(b1);
Console.WriteLine(b2);
Console.WriteLine(b3);
```

Should Print

```
False
True
False
```

But it prints:

```
False
False
False
```

Is this the desired behavior or is a bug?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/17959

Comment: @aybe, i have to say, that the guy on the issue is completely right, it should reflect the change of the TextWriters/Readers of the Console Class, not the SO the app is running on.